# How To Get The Member Count Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to add a status in my discord bot, which shows the total number of members, the bot is watching like all bots show for exmaple.

If my bot is added in 2 servers, 1st one has 20 members, second one has 30 members.
= 50 Members Total, How Can I show this???? Can anybody help??

[Proof That The Code Is 100% Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrw4P.png)

```py
def find_members():
    l = str(client.guilds)
    l = l.split(" ")
    f = 0
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if "member_count=" in l[i]:
            s = l[i]
            d = ""
            for i in s:
                if i.isnumeric():
                    d += i
                else:
                    pass
            f += int(d)
        else:
            pass
    return f
```

Comment: Also I am not asking for like um status or something, I am asking that how to display the total number of servers and members the bot is watching :) Hope you guys understood my problem ;)

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service - what you have you tried? What part of this seems difficult to you? Have you had a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client)? [Guild object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild).

Comment: @ESloman I Know I know, stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, and also The thing which I exactly want to get is the member count of every guild in which bot is added that's it, :)

Comment: Okay, but what code have you got that shows you've tried to do this? How can I help when you haven't showed us what you've tried?

Comment: @ESloman ```for i in range(len(client.guilds)):
        print(client.guilds[i])``` I tried this but I idk how to get the member count

Comment: By doing this, i get the server name not the member count

Comment: Can you update the question with the code that you've tried? It looks like you haven't looked at the docs either. [The guild object doc is here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client%20start#discord.Guild). Can you see some attributes that might be useful?

Comment: @ESloman Let me check out the docs once! thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function can be simplified significantly. [`Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client%20start#discord.Guild) has a `member_count` property which is the number of members in the guild. You do have to have the `members` intent enabled for that though. But using that, getting the member count is trivial.

There's also no need to make the list of guilds a list and then make it a list again - just iterate over it directly. With Python, we can iterate over the items in a list doing `for thing in things` so we don't need to use `range` here either; there's no real need to know the index of the guild in the list.

```py
def find_members(client: discord.Client) -> int:
    total_member_count = 0
    for guild in client.guilds:
        total_member_count += guild.member_count
    return total_member_count
```

You can now call the `find_members` function and pass in the `client` (or remove it and rely on the client already defined in the file).

Comment: Ayo! Your Method is really really awesome, but I want to know, that if the bot is added in so many servers, will it work really slow or fast?? thanks for helping btw :D

Comment: @BadriVishalManiTripathi this method will require that the guilds are fetched and loaded in the cache if the're not there will be 0 users counted for this guild. you could load the guilds in the startup, else they will be loaded only if there is an event or so on ion the server e.g. member join. But if they are cached it will be really fast for every run

Answer (score -1):

I've found a solution which you can use to get the total count of members a bot is watching

```py
def find_members():
    l = str(client.guilds)
    l = l.split(" ")
    f = 0
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if "member_count=" in l[i]:
            s = l[i]
            d = ""
            for i in s:
                if i.isnumeric():
                    d += i
                else:
                    pass
            f += int(d)
        else:
            pass
    return f
```

For Proof Checkout The Image URL In The Question!

Comment: That's a really bad way to do it. `guild.members` is an iterable with all the members of that guild.....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

so there is a easy method by using `bot.users` function, the only thing you need is to enable `server member intent` on the discord bot dashboard [image] and then just add this piece of code,

```py
len(bot.users)
```

Comment: Wow! I thought the code is so small maybe it wouldn't work, but wow, it works!! thanks for helping!!

Comment: glad to hear that, only downside of this code is it needs server member intent, which gets difficult to obtain once you get verified. and if the answers helps you than make it as accept, this will help other person visiting this